# Facebook API notification send but not received

Tags: facebook, api, notifications

I have tested the Facebook API to send notification though the graph explorer. 
The result is success but the notification was not received by the user. Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: where did you check? they do not show up on mobile afaik. did you authorize the app?

Comment: I checked it on my laptop. Yes, I authorized the app!

Comment: @luschn any idea why?

Comment: Any idea why guys?